# cover page for web game, how to grab an element by its class rather than ID?

Tags: javascript, css

unsure as to why this function isn't working to to take my javascript function and change the opacity on the css sheet.

i have a variable already named and the html to that button

```
let playGameButton = document.getElementById("introbutton");

function play() {
  playGameButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("header").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById(".score").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById(".result").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById(".choices").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("#action-message").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("#stupidbutton").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById(".intro").style.opacity = 0;
  });
}
play();
```

this doesnt play out right, ive even though about creating a windows.onload function and doing it the long way, however i would like to get this working.

Comment: not sure how your html looks like but it seems like you're trying to getElementsByClassName("score")[0] and getElementsByTagName("header")[0]. Or if you're trying to change all of that class or all of those tags you would need a loop

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how you are uding getRlementsById. This only works when you have an `id=` in the html, you can't use it for classes, and you must not use #. You can use getElementsByClassName as eylion says, returning an array that you have to iterate over, and again, don't use a "."

Without looking at your html, I'm guessing that all of these are ids and you may have to update your html